# referring to arrays from another function

Tags: python, arrays, function

I have some code with several user defined functions. I want one of the functions to use the output from another, but apparently Python will not let me with the following code below. Python does not seem to like the fact that array1 is not defined within function2 itself. Any suggestions? function1 is called first, so my logic was that array1 should be defined before function 2 is called...but maybe I am misunderstanding how Python works. (This is a simplfied version of the actual code, but it boils down to the same issue)

```
def function1():
    some_input=1
    some_other_input=2
    array1=[]
    array1.append(some_input)
    array1.append(some_other_input)


def function2():
    for i in range(len(array1)):
    print(array1[i])

function1()
function2()
```

Comment: How about using array1 as the output of function1 and then send it as a parameter and use it in function2?

Comment: You need to look into `return`, passing arguments to functions, and assigning the returned value to a name. All of these will be covered in introductory tutorials to functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When python searches a variable it follows **LEGB** rule

so it will search in Local then in Enclosure then in Global and at last in the builtins, so to make your list(array) accessible you need to make it Global

**Approach 1**

create in function1 and pass it to function2

```
def func1():
    arr=[]
    arr.append(1)
    return arr


def func2(arr):
    arr.append(2)
    print(arr)

arr = func1()
func2(arr)
```

**Approach 2**

Make your list global and access that using "global" keyword

```
arr = []

def func1():
    global arr
    arr.append(1)

def func2():
    global arr
    arr.append(2)
    print(arr)

func1()
func2()
```

Answer (score 0):

The following would work, pass the array that `function1()` returns into `function2()`. Another possible way would be to declare `array1` as global variable.

```
def function1():
    some_input=1
    some_other_input=2
    array1=[]
    array1.append(some_input)
    array1.append(some_other_input)
    return array1


def function2(arr):
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        print(arr[i])

arr = function1()
function2(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible implementation below:

```
def function1():
    some_input=1
    some_other_input=2
    array1=[]
    array1.append(some_input)
    array1.append(some_other_input)
    return array1


def function2(array):
    for i in range(len(array)):
        print(array[i])

array = function1()
function2(array)
```